# ActionController::RoutingError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I dont understand this error from my test
`Failure/Error: get "new"
ActionController::RoutingError:
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"user"}`

My routes file

`Station::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :new => "new" }`

and here is my test

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe UserController do

    it "should registrer new user" do
        get "new"
        fill_in "Email",                 :with => "abc@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",              :with => "abc123"
        click_button "Sign up"
        response.should have_content("Welcome! You have registrered successfully.")
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller hash is incorrect. You have `:controllers => { :new => "new" }`, and what this is saying is that you want your 'User' model to handled by devise through a controller called 'new'. This should be changed to, for example `:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }`, assuming the name of your controller is 'Registrations'

Comment: the name of my controller is usercontroler... i changed it but the error is still there, well in the original controller i haven't any code

Comment: basically I need that on the site a new user signs up and take him to the profile page anymore

Comment: Have you checkout out the documentation on github? In particular note that if you define a custom controller, it should inherit from the appropriate devise controller. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise